# Variables method names for classes

Tags: php

How can I call a function in a class that depends on a user's input.

So if the user sent 2011 I want to call the method `$record->show_2011()`

if they sent the input 2012 I want to call the method `$record->show_2012()`

else I want to call `$record->show()`

How do I pass in the user's input into the method name to call it?

Comment: Probably best to map incoming variables to method / function names.

Comment: Can't you just pass it _into_ a function as a param instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
$functionToCall = 'show_' . $userInput;
$record->$functionToCall();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the function name in a variable first, e.g. `$function_name = 'set'.$request->getFirstProperty();` and then `$record->$function_name();`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
$record->{'show'}();

$record->{'show_' . $variableThatHoldsTheRestOfFunctionName}();
```